# Dual boot (Windows 10 and Ubuntu 10) boots straight into Windows

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, multi-boot

I recently re-installed Windows 10 and Ubuntu 19.04 indual boot (curiously, the issue I am about to describe was not present before). When I boot my laptop it goes straight into windows rather than the menu where I can decide between Ubuntu, Windows  (the one with purple background).
I tried to fix this with:

- `grub customizer`
- in the UEFI settings
- with `efibootmgr` (running from an ubuntu live USB drive, [as described here](https://www.lifewire.com/fix-uefi-bootloader-issues-when-dual-booting-2200655))
- with `boot-repair` (which produced [this report](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MNt6nyVvfH/))

Nothing solved the issue. Any ideas?

p.s: my laptop in a Dell Chromebook 13 (aka LULU) with full UEFI firmware by [MrChromebox](https://mrchromebox.tech/#home)

Comment: Did you install windows before Ubuntu?

Comment: Check this out. https://askubuntu.com/questions/62440/is-it-possible-to-boot-ubuntu-using-the-windows-bootloader

Comment: @Pancakedinner yes I did install Windows before Ubuntu. I checked the thread you suggested but I do not know which answer I should follow. It talks about MBR while in my case I have a EFI partition. Doesn't that change things?